# What are exact feed powers per each pet level in RotMG?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

[Here](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/pet-feeding) feed power per pet ability "stage" in Realm of the Mad God is given. But where can I find more exact information? Like a table, that would show how much I need to feed a pets ability-X from level Y to level Y+1.

I guess this information is available, since [here on a random player page (see Pet Yard section)](https://www.realmeye.com/pets-of/Draagseom), for example, one can see how much feed power for an existing pet is required to achieve next level from current state. But I am failing to find a full table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OtherBill said in his topic ["A Mathematical Approach to Pet Levelling"](http://community.kabam.com/forums/showthread.php?262555-A-Mathematical-Approach-to-Pet-Levelling) under Key Assumptions:

> The key data here are that improving the pet's first ability from lvl1 to lvl2 requires 20fp, the second ability from lvl1 to lvl2 requires 31fp, the third ability from lvl1 to lvl2 requires 67fp, and everything from that point on increases by 8% from one level to the next. This has largely been verified to be accurate for most key values, but some anecdotal experiences may vary slightly from this.

I've looked at multiple sources and they have all came to about the same conclusion. From level 2 onwards the amount of feed power required increases by 8 percent. The RotMG Japanese Wiki also came to the [same conclusion](http://wikiwiki.jp/rmd/?Pet%20Yard#necessary)[(translated version)](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?act=url&depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http://wikiwiki.jp/rmd/%3FPet%2520Yard&usg=ALkJrhjK2HSYqzWqcYf4ON12go_zN_NdsQ#necessary):

> NextFeedPower = 1.08 ^ (A-1) * 400 / B
>
> A: Current ability level B: and if 1st if the 20, 2nd if 13, 3rd 6